# Why is Eclipse suggesting I convert to an Xtext project?

Tags: java, css, eclipse, xtext

I have a [Java Eclipse project](https://github.com/Stevoisiak/Virtual-Game-Shelf) with a stylesheet for JavaFX saved in `resources/stylesheet.css`

[image: Package Explorer]

Anytime I open `stylesheet.css` in the Package Explorer, Eclipse asks me if I want to convert my project to an Xtext project.

[image: Prompt to convert to Xtest project]

**Why is Eclipse offering to convert my Java project into an Xtext project every time I open my `.css` stylesheet? Is there a specific reason to convert to an Xtext project?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use the stylesheet for JavaFX.

I had the same issue, it was solved by converting the project to a JavaFX project ([e(fx)clipse required](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html)).

Currently there's no direct way to convert a project to a JavaFX project. You'll have to create a new JavaFX project and copy over everything.

```
New -> Project -> JavaFX -> JavaFX Project
```

Comment: This answer explains how I can fix the issue, though I'm still unsure **why** it suggested Xtext, or what the advantages of recreating the project as a JavaFX project are.

Comment: Truth said I have no idea why this is so, I don't even know what Xtext is... All I can think is that Xtext also uses css and eclipse tries to help you, unaware of javafx.

Comment: Ok. So to clarify, you're suggesting I reimport my code as a new JavaFX Eclipse project? (I already have E(fx)clipse installed and have the project compiling successfully)